# inexplicable ANRs when executing service

Tags: android, android-intentservice, android-anr-dialog

I have an IntentService that I use to send logs to our logging server.

I've received reports of this app in the field exiting with no reason, no ANR, no "unfortunately...", just a silent "crash to desktop" (It's not a "crash" - crashlytics doesn't catch it. The app just disappears, no transition animations or anything) and this seems to be the problem that's causing it.
Occasionally I get an ANR dialog that doesn't seem to affect the app at all other than interrupting the user.

I've researched how to debug ANRs, but nothing seems to point to why these are occurring, other than that it happens while executing this service.

First I tried dumping the anr trace. The only thread that looked like it had issues was this one, but it doesn't know what the GCDaemon was trying to lock ([full anr trace here](https://pastebin.com/8FLzCVf8)):

```
"GCDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=11 Blocked
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c9c200 self=0xaf211400
| sysTid=12503 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xaf225a80
| state=S schedstat=( 2357890680 895472914 1619 ) utm=195 stm=40 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0xb3c46000-0xb3c48000 stackSize=1036KB
| held mutexes=
native: #00 pc 00010110  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
native: #01 pc 000aad07  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::Wait(art::Thread*)+82)
native: #02 pc 0012f793  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::WaitForConcurrentGCRequest(art::Thread*)+90)
native: #03 pc 000003db  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_waitForConcurrentGCRequest__+82)
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.waitForConcurrentGCRequest(Native method)
- waiting to lock an unknown object
at java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon.run(Daemons.java:334)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have tried strict mode, but I don't get any strict mode violations around when the dialog shows, only the following dump:

```
02-14 15:16:54.434 821-1014/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.myApp
                                             PID: 26032
                                             Reason: Executing service com.myApp/.services.LoggerService
                                             Load: 11.8 / 12.09 / 12.38
                                             CPU usage from 1377ms to -6213ms ago:
                                               55% 821/system_server: 19% user + 36% kernel / faults: 9743 minor
                                               5.9% 1758/com.google.android.gms: 3.1% user + 2.7% kernel / faults: 1739 minor
                                               5.5% 1188/com.android.systemui: 2.9% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 2141 minor
                                               0% 287/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2917 minor
                                               3.9% 1461/com.android.phone: 1.5% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 2380 minor
                                               3.8% 26032/com.myApp: 2.2% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 6809 minor
                                               3% 4767/com.twotechnologies.n5service: 0.9% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 860 minor
                                               2.2% 212/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
                                               1.7% 1542/com.sec.imsservice: 0.5% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 1529 minor
                                               0% 1455/com.android.nfc: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 701 minor
                                               0.7% 19190/adbd: 0.1% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 129 minor
                                               0% 1447/com.android.server.telecom: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 803 minor
                                               0% 2030/com.android.incallui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 656 minor
                                               0.6% 2246/mpdecision: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
                                               0.6% 3069/mdnsd: 0.1% user + 0.5% kernel
                                               0.5% 213/dhd_rxf: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                               0% 2001/com.samsung.vmmhux: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 591 minor
                                               0.3% 20989/kworker/u:3: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                               0.2% 211/dhd_watchdog_th: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                               0.2% 9206/kworker/0:0H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                               0.2% 22900/logcat: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                               0.2% 25851/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                               0.2% 26330/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.2% 26361/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                               0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 20 minor
                                               0.1% 2/kthreadd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 7/kworker/u:0H: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 33/kworker/u:1H: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 171/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 205/mmcqd/1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0% 223/jbd2/mmcblk0p25: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                               0.1% 256/surfaceflinger: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                               0.1% 281/edmaudit: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 1984/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                               0.1% 2583/com.vcast.mediamanager: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 2874/tv.peel.samsung.app: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                               0.1% 22944/perfd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                              +0% 28214/diag_uart_log: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                              +0% 28215/migration/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                              +0% 28216/kworker/3:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                              +0% 28217/kworker/3:0H: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                              +0% 28218/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                              +0% 28219/kworker/3:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                              +0% 28220/kworker/3:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                             58% TOTAL: 19% user + 35% kernel + 0% iowait + 3.5% softirq
                                             CPU usage from 5173ms to 5712ms later:
                                               16% 821/system_server: 3.3% user + 13% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                                                 13% 1014/ActivityManager: 3.3% user + 10% kernel
                                                 1.6% 835/FinalizerDaemon: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
                                               2.1% 1758/com.google.android.gms: 2.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
                                                 1% 27483/mdns-receive: 1% user + 0% kernel
                                               0.9% 1//init: 0% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 9 minor
                                               1.7% 212/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
                                               1.1% 4767/com.twotechnologies.n5service: 1.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
                                                 1.1% 4789/b: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                 1.1% 4790/h: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
                                              +0% 28214/diag_uart_log: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                             24% TOTAL: 5.4% user + 17% kernel + 1.3% softirq
```

I have tried ANRWatchDog: https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog which does not throw an exception when the ANR dialog shows.

Lastly, I've tried REMOVING ALL LOGIC from the service's onHandleIntent, and I still get the ANR dialog fairly regularly. As in, this is the service's onHandleIntent:

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
}
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you have any additional code in your IntentService?

Comment: I do. In the service's onCreate I initialize an SSLSocketFactory. I also have static methods that construct the intents that are sent to the IntentService. The ANR dialogs happen a good while after starting the service for the first time, though.

Comment: Just a few weeks ago, I found that my app occasionally reports ANR because some memory leaks. Try using Android Profiler, and Do some tests to check that your App doesn't have memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue by just not using an IntentService and switching to a set of static methods that fire off AsyncTasks. I still don't know what the root cause of my initial issue was.